# Reading Excel worksheet using PHPExcel is not giving the expected results

Tags: php, phpexcel

I seem to be having 2 issues reading data from an Excel 2007 workbook using PHPExcel:

1. No document properties are being found;
2. Values from cells are unformatted.

**sample.xlsx**:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+
| Office | Hr no PFU | Hr $ no PFU |
+--------+-----------+-------------+
| AA01   | 18.50     | $ 13.14     |
| BW23   | 1020.03   | $ 123.23    |
+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

- The values in the cells below Hr no PFU have been formatted using Accounting of 2 decimal places.
- The values in the cells below Hr $ no PFU have been formatted also using Accounting of 2 decimals, with the symbol $.
- The workbook also has document properties for Author, Subject, and Title.

Tweak of **exampleWorkBookReader02.php** (one of the examples provided in the documentation):

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/sample.xlsx';

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

/**  Read an array list of any custom properties for this document  **/
$customPropertyList = $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->getCustomProperties();
foreach($customPropertyList as $customPropertyName) {
    echo $customPropertyName,'<br />';
}

/**  Read cell values **/
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

var_dump($sheetData);
```

(BTW The original script using a file from the documentation outputs the list of custom properties WITHOUT any of their values.)

Now, I am only having this problem with Excel 2007 workbooks. So this makes me wonder whether I missing one of the [requirements](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Requirements), but I don't believe so:

- PHP version 5.5
- php_zip and php_xml which are included by default, no?
- php_gd2 is enabled

Is there a way to check whether something is missing?

Comment: The unformatted values problem may be because you're using Accounting format and 2 decimal places - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25908380/328817).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extension being installed and enabled are two different things.
Check if all PHPEXcel dependencies are installed
Then check their configuration files or the php.ini to see if they are indeed enabled.

From the [PHPExcel docs](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/107442) it is clear that it does support Excel2007 and it also worked on your dev env, right? Well check the dependencies and see what's wrong there.

Also is there some error aynwhere in the system logs?Maybe PHPExcel is already complaining about this"Behind the scenes"?

Also you may want to consider using something like (or exactly) [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) for environment sync - this way you will always be sure that your env is the same on your dev machine and on your servers.